# Copy a column of data from the second row until the last row with data in it and paste as the last row in a column on another sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a VBA code to copy data from the second cell "A2" down to the last cell with data in it (this range will change). I then want to paste that data starting at the last row of column A on another sheet.

My VBA code as of now seems to do nothing. Can someone help me figure out why?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddNotes()

Dim lastRow1 As String
Dim lastRow2 As String

lastRow1 = Sheets("PropertiesToMatch").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("PropertiesToMatch").Range("A2" & lastRow1).Copy

lastRow2 = Sheets("PropertyNotesToUpload").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheets("PropertyNotesToUpload").Range("A" & lastRow2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Why isn't it working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @BigBen yeah I realized that and deleted that comment :)

Comment: You may want to change `Dim lastRow1 As String` and `Dim lastRow2 As String` to `As Long`?

Comment: @ZackE that is a good catch. I will incorporate into my answer.

Comment: Just one more observation.  I believe it would be more prudent to qualify the sheets and ranges and instead of copying them make the ranges equal to each other from a performance standpoint.  Granted without knowing how large the data set is it may not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
.Range("A2" & lastRow1)
```

to

```
.Range("A2:A" & lastRow1)
```

The first is only *one* cell, the second is the range you want.

Also, change

```
Dim lastRow1 As String
Dim lastRow2 As String
```

to

```
Dim lastRow1 As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
```

because [`Range.Row`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.row) is a `Long`, not a `String`.

Answer (score -2):

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPaste()
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer

With Sheets("PropertiesToMatch")
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
j = 2

For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
Sheets("PropertiesToMatch").Cells(i, 1).Copy
Sheets("PropertyNotesToUpload").Cells(j, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

j = j + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: There are lots of things wrong with this answer. Use `Long` instead of `Integer`, no loop is needed, and you're looping from the bottom to the top, among others.

Comment: Thanks for your corrections. Genuinely curious, why use Long instead of Integer? As for the reversed loop I interpreted the "I then want to paste that data starting at the last row of column A on another sheet" as I want the last cell of column of A in the first sheet to be the first cell of column A in the second sheet.

Comment: I can see how you might take that away from the question, but OP's code is pretty clear what the goal is, and there's an accepted answer already.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long) for why not to use Integer. Main reason is that there's a possible Overflow error - Excel has more rows than Integer can handle.

Comment: Apologies if my first comment came off as rude in any way, I could have been more gentle about it.